# How can I divide up a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, fork

I have an enormous timeseries of functions stored in a pandas dataframe in an HDF5 store and I want to make plots of a certain transform of every function in the timeseries. Since the number of plots is so large, and plotting them takes so long, I've used `fork()` and `numpy.array_split()` to break the indices up and run several plots in parallel.

Doing things this way means that every process has a copy of the whole timeseries. Since what limits how many processes I can run is the total amount of memory I use, I would like to be able to have each process store only it's own chunk of the dataframe.

How can I split up a pandas dataframe?

Comment: do you mean HDF5 store?

Comment: The HDF5 storage only has one object in it, the pandas dataframe. I'll correct the "HDF Store" typo in a little bit.

Comment: you should split your data up into several smaller frames and write them to the same (or different stores). they can be read by multiple processes (but only write from as final process!

Comment: @Jeff: I don't know how to split dataframes. That's what the question is about.

Comment: What are the criteria for the split? Before/after a certain date? A fixed number of rows?

Comment: @Paul H: I want to split it into `n` roughly even pieces, each having a certain number of columns and every row.

Comment: i guess i'm confused. are these so big that using `iloc` won't work with @Jeff's suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.array_split` works pretty well for this usecase.

```
 [40]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,10))

In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
0 -1.998163 -1.973708  0.461369 -0.575661  0.862534 -1.326168  1.164199 -1.004121  1.236323 -0.339586
1 -0.591188 -0.162782  0.043923  0.101241  0.120330 -1.201497 -0.108959 -0.033221  0.145400 -0.324831
2  0.114842  0.200597  2.792904  0.769636 -0.698700 -0.544161  0.838117 -0.013527 -0.623317 -1.461193
3  1.309628 -0.444961  0.323008 -1.409978 -0.697961  0.132321 -2.851494  1.233421 -1.540319  1.107052
4  0.436368  0.627954 -0.942830  0.448113 -0.030464  0.764961 -0.241905 -0.620992  1.238171 -0.127617
```

Just pretty-printing as you get a list of 3 elements here.

```
In [43]: for dfs in np.array_split(df,3,axis=1):
   ....:     print dfs, "\n"
   ....:     
          0         1         2         3
0 -1.998163 -1.973708  0.461369 -0.575661
1 -0.591188 -0.162782  0.043923  0.101241
2  0.114842  0.200597  2.792904  0.769636
3  1.309628 -0.444961  0.323008 -1.409978
4  0.436368  0.627954 -0.942830  0.448113 

          4         5         6
0  0.862534 -1.326168  1.164199
1  0.120330 -1.201497 -0.108959
2 -0.698700 -0.544161  0.838117
3 -0.697961  0.132321 -2.851494
4 -0.030464  0.764961 -0.241905 

          7         8         9
0 -1.004121  1.236323 -0.339586
1 -0.033221  0.145400 -0.324831
2 -0.013527 -0.623317 -1.461193
3  1.233421 -1.540319  1.107052
```

Comment: I am getting "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'size'" with Pandas v0.15.0 and Numpy v1.9.1? @Jeff